# JS Map (like Google Map but few features) implementation for IE8

Tags: javascript, maps

Is there any js solution of  map implementation which supports IE 8 , amMap does not.Or  any solution which is faster in any language, I know there are lot of solution but very few for  8th version of IE with Zooming support

Answer (score 0):

maybe you will have a look at http://underscorejs.org/ which should work for IE8 too.
The equivalent would be [_.map()](http://underscorejs.org/#map).